# regular expression to match date in MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss format

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, timestamp

I want to check the DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss format. Can anyone say the regular expression for DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss format?

Comment: a regular expression isn't going to be able to validate a date - considering not all months have the same number of days, and february has 28 or 29 days depending on the year - no wonder you haven't even attempted to do it yourself - it's just too crazy

Comment: Depending on how strict you want to validate the date, Regex probably isn't the right tool. Have you yet tried any date-focused libraries? For example, [moment.js supports format-specific parsing](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/).

Comment: Is there any specific reason for validating date in regex?

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}

var reg =/\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}-\d{4}\s\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}/; 
var givenDate = '13-10-2000 10:10:10'; 
reg.test(givenDate);
```

This should work for you.

Comment: is `99-99-2018 78:87:98` a valid date? :p

Comment: Yeah you are correct @Bravo. But we are checking for date and time format so there will be less chance where there will be string like 99-99-999 99:99:99 which is not a date.

Comment: `^(((0[1-9]|1[012])-[0-2]\d)|((0[1,3-9]|1[012])-30)|((0?[1,3,5,7,8]|1[02])-31))-\d{4}\s(0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-3])(:([0-5]\d)){2}$` - the only failure with this is that it allows feb 29 every year (and yes, if this is not the most efficient regex it just shows I'm no good at regex :p )

Comment: please can you say it for MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss

Comment: @Chanducandy 
Added example

Comment: its not throwing any error even if i give time like this "99-99-2000 10:10:10"